# Can I write JSP script in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, jsp

I am making a JSP program and all it does is show the date:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <%
    System.out.println( "Evaluating date now" );
    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
%>
<p>Hello, the date is
    <%
    out.println( date );
    out.println( "<BR>Your machine's address is " );
    out.println(request.getRemoteHost());
%> 
</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

On wordpress, all the JSP script shows up as normal text and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no. JSP files must be run on an application server such as `tomcat`. The information [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/498802/gc/Wordpress-jsp) might be helpful.